# Connecting Python to Google Analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-oauth

I am up to the creating my credentials but I noticed this:

"The consent screen tells your users who is requesting access to their data and what kind of data you're asking to access."

Does this mean the customers on my webstore will be prompted with a consent screen?

I have searched for an answer to this online, but haven't come across anything specific and have been following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py

I want to make sure my webstore isn't effected at all by making this connection.

All I am looking to do with this is make reporting easier.

Any advice on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I do not know, if that is mandatory step in Google Analytics (https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsseo/troubleshooting/how-to-get-google-analytics-api-keys.html ), but it is good (and at least in EU mandatory) practice to have consent screen on any data gathering app (GDPR requirement). Ref: [Accept] Cookies in browsers, too.

Comment: @chazly You may not be finding the information you are looking for because you may not be Googling the right keywords. What you are doing is using Google OAuth to gain an access token to be able to use the Google Analytics API. Please see this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 . When you  register your app to get your credentials, Google has a sort of wizard that ask questions to help determine the grant type and scope your app needs. Depend on your answers and the scope your app needs, then yes, users will need to sign in w/ Google and grant consent to your app.

Comment: @chazly I would need more information about what you are trying to do to help you determine the proper scope for your app/project that needs the token to access the Google Analytics API. If you are just trying to access GA data from YOUR* own Google account, this is a different story. If you are trying to access data from many user's Google accounts, then your app will definitely need their consent to access their data.

Comment: @Mika72 this is a mandatory step in oauth2 when accessing private data. This predates GDPR by around 14 years

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies, the scope of my project is to simply be able to access my own google analytics data (which comes from my eCommerce web store) through python rather than logging into my google analytics account. I will then be able to do quick automated reporting. Let me know if this answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

> "The consent screen tells your users who is requesting access to their data and what kind of data you're asking to access."
>
> Does this mean the customers on my webstore will be prompted with a consent screen?

Yes Google analytics data is private user data.  If you want to access a users data then they will have to login to their Google account and consent to you accessing that data.

The user consent is an integral part of [Oauth2](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hunt-oauth-v2-user-a4c-01.html)

[image]

In the above image Google Analytics windows is requesting access to the users Google analytics data.  If the user accepts then the application will be allowed to access the data.

### service account

If you are trying to share your own google analytics data with your users. Then you should be looking into using a service account instead.